# How to Create PDF from file using Acrobat SDK with C# or VB.NET?

Tags: c#, acrobat

Here I am using Acrobat 7 to create PDF, using the File->Create PDF->From File option.

Now I want to do this process by using Acrobat SDK with C# or VB.NET, so please give me a suggestion how can I do.

**Note:**

Here I am using **DOC** file to convert.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Time being I got answer for my question,

here I am used VB.NET with Acrobat jsobj

Please refer below link for reference

Reference Link : http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=JavaScript_SectionPage.70.1.html&accessible=true

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Adobe allows to create some PDF like that but look for free libraries like SharpPDF and PDF SCout it's really easy to do.

Instead you can use [PDFScoutVb.net dll](http://bytescout.com/examples/pdfdocscout_vb_net.zip)

[Tutorial: how to create PDF document in Visual Basic.NET (Visual Studio.NET) using PDFDoc Scout library](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfdocscoutsdk/pdfdocscout_example_vb_net.html)

Comment: well Every thing ok already i am know those and all, but i want to convert Doc into PDF. is there is any open source to convert Doc to PDF.

Comment: Surely but document save as in PDF format is available from MS Office 2007, but i am using MS Office 2003. wat can i do?